# Unexpected result with TRegex matching a unicode string. Is this a bug?

Tags: regex, debugging, unicode, pcre, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am using delphi 10.1.
I have an unexpected result doing the following

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Match: TMatch;
  Regex: TRegex;
  Perl: TPerlRegEx;
const
  s1 = 'Réaitaei: test123';
  s2 = 'Réàààaitaei: test123';
  s3 = 'Réàààààààààaitaei: test123';
  pattern = '(.*): ';
begin
  Regex := TRegex.Create(pattern);
  Match := Regex.Match(s1);
  Assert(Match.Success);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Match.Groups[1].Value);
  Match := Regex.Match(s2);
  Assert(Match.Success);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Match.Groups[1].Value);
  Match := Regex.Match(s3);
  Assert(Match.Success);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Match.Groups[1].Value);

  Perl := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  Perl.RegEx := pattern;
  Perl.Compile;
  Perl.Subject := s1;
  Assert(Perl.Match);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Perl.Groups[1]);
  Perl.Subject := s2;
  Assert(Perl.Match);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Perl.Groups[1]);
  Perl.Subject := s3;
  Assert(Perl.Match);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Perl.Groups[1]);
end;
```

i get :

> Réaitaei
>  Réàààaitaei: t
>  Réàààààààààaitaei: test
>   Réaitaei
>  Réàààaitaei
>  Réàààààààààaitaei

So `TPerlRegex` works but not `TRegex` when doc says that `TRegex` is just a wrapper to `TPerlRegex`.

Am I missing sth or it s a bug ?

I found a post from Marco Cantu saying that since delphi xe7, delphi uses pcre 8.35 so I am not expecting any problem from using unicode.

Comment: Same in Berlin, but Tokyo 10.2.1 works. Both give a memory leak, you aren't calling Free for Perl.

Comment: Thanks. I just realised my title is not a question so i am gonna rephrase that so there can be an answer. You might want to summit your comment as an answer, if you think it s definitely a bug.

Comment: Not sure, but this works in Berlin: Assert(TRegex.Match('Réàààààààààaitaei: test123', '(.*): ').Groups[1].Value = 'Réàààààààààaitaei');

Comment: Could be this one [RSP-15145](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15145)

Comment: Ty. I installed delphi tokyo starter and my code now works and it is indeed the same as the bug report you indicated. Even found another one [RSP-17697](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17697) wich is related.

Comment: Are you gonna post an answer that i can accept or should i do it so we can close this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [RSP-17697](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17697) solves this issue in Tokyo 10.2.1. When you run a compare on the relevant units you can see that TBytes was changed to Unicode String. I've checked my re-used RegEx and its not affected but for anyone not sure and using Berlin or lower use the class method to assure all works: `TRegex.Match('Réàààààààààaitaei: test123', '(.*): ').Groups[1].Value = 'Réàààààààààaitaei'`

That would be one heck of a bug to hunt down